# Selenium Python Script throws no element error exception even though the x path is right?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://paytm.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("login").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//md-input-container[@class='md-default-theme md-input-invalid']/input[@id='input_0']").send_keys("99991221212")
```

In the above code, I have verified the xpath using fire bug its highlighting the correct element. But when the script run its failing? Can you help me folks?

Answer (score 3):

In selenium each frame is treated individually. Since the login is in a separate `iframe` element, you need to switch to it first using:

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
```

**Before** trying to interact with it's elements.

Or in this case, you would wait for the frame to exist, and it would be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://paytm.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "login"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))

_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"input_0")))
_input.send_keys("99991221212")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until `input` element visible on the page as below :-

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://paytm.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "login"))).click()

#now switch to iframe first      
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))

input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "input_0")))
input.send_keys("99991221212")
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: @Subbu did you try with `XPath` or `id`??

Comment: @Subbu as i seeing the input element is inside a `iframe`..you need switch that frame before finding input element.. see updated answer..